# How do I get log files from an deployed iOS app that is not crashed?

Tags: ios, iphone, logging, crash-reports, diagnostics

I know that it is possible to get crash reports from an appstore customer, either using xcode -> organizer -> crash, or telling the customer to go to settings -> privacy -> diagnostics.

However, the app did not crash (just hangs) and there is no crash report created. I would like to get the regular console output of the app to gather some more informations. Is there a way to force the creation of a log file, either by iphone settings or by changing my app?

Comment: Hello. Were you able to get an answer/solution for this? I am also faced with a similar situation, where the app doesn't crash but hangs for certain users. So looking for a way to get my hands on the Console output without a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this [ios_deploy](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy) You will get all logs from the deployed app on device.